# formatting for "phone" not working

Tags: html, css

I am currently developing my first chrome extension that uses html/css/javascript. I have a problem, and so far none of the questions in stackoverflow seem to answer my problem.

I have a layout that looks like a phone, just like an IPhone. Basically, my button inside the `homepage-bottom` ID `div` is not working properly. I want the `homepage-bottom-inside` ID `div`(it's color is black) round.

It currently looks like this.

Please explain my error, and fix the code.

```css
#homepage-bottom-content {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#homepage-bottom-content-inside {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border: #E6E6E6 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage-bottom">
  <div id="homepage-bottom-content">
    <div id="homepage-bottom-content-inside"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EXTRA**

This is how the overall "phone" looks.

```css
#homepage {
  margin: auto;
  height: 620px;
  width: 330px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: black 7px solid;
}
#homepage-content {
  margin: auto;
  height: 470px;
  cursor: cell;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  border: 3px black solid;
}
#homepage-bottom-content {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#homepage-bottom-content-inside {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border: #E6E6E6 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage">
  <div id="homepage-top">
    <div id="homepage-top-content">
      <div style="background-color: black; height: 15px; width: 15px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 100px;"></div>
      <div style="background-color: black; height: 10px; width: 50px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px; border-radius: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="homepage-content">
  </div>
  <div id="homepage-bottom">
    <div id="homepage-bottom-content">
      <div id="homepage-bottom-content-inside"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `padding-top` is part of total height, so `height:40px` + `padding-top:10px` does it for `homepage-bottom-content`.

Be aware that the `border` thickness is also part of the total height.

```css
#homepage-bottom-content {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#homepage-bottom-content-inside {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border: #E6E6E6 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage-bottom">
  <div id="homepage-bottom-content">
    <div id="homepage-bottom-content-inside"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Extra

Your phone fixed:

```css
#homepage {
  margin: auto;
  height: 620px;
  width: 330px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: black 7px solid;
}
#homepage-content {
  margin: auto;
  height: 470px;
  cursor: cell;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  border: 3px black solid;
}
#homepage-bottom-content {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#homepage-bottom-content-inside {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border: #E6E6E6 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage">
  <div id="homepage-top">
    <div id="homepage-top-content">
      <div style="background-color: black; height: 15px; width: 15px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 100px;"></div>
      <div style="background-color: black; height: 10px; width: 50px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px; border-radius: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="homepage-content">
  </div>
  <div id="homepage-bottom">
    <div id="homepage-bottom-content">
      <div id="homepage-bottom-content-inside"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I upvoted you, but I figured out my answer myself after I fiddled around with the code.